# Add header row to listbox

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am using listboxes to display data in userforms in word. However I am not able to set header captions or figure out how to make it possible to click on the header to sort by that column.

```
GUI.Search_ListBox.Clear
GUI.Search_ListBox.ColumnCount = 5 ' Columns
GUI.Search_ListBox.ColumnWidths = "120;80;70;120;300"
GUI.Search_ListBox.ColumnHeads = True
'GUI.Search_ListBox.RowSource = "Hello;gkjfl;hsjgh;hdfjhgkj;fdjghjkdf" 'here it fails!!!
```

[image]

Comment: Oh, there's an error.  That would have been handy to know before I posted an answer.

Comment: Which part of that gibberish is supposed to be the headings?

Comment: VBA in Word does not support RowSource property for lists, even in UserForms. Only Excel does.

Answer (score 0):

---

**With VBA**, simply set the **`ListBox.ColumnHeads`** Property to `True`.

---

Alternatively, you can also change the setting in the ActiveX control's `Properties` dialog:

[image: Properties]

If the <sub>[image: Properties]</sub> button is disabled on the ribbon, you'll have to enter <sub>[image: Design Mode]</sub> first.

---

### More Information:

- [ListBox.ColumnHeads Property (Access)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/access-vba/articles/listbox-columnheads-property-access)

---

### EDIT:

You need to specify the headings in the rowsource:

> Column headings are enabled and either field captions, field names, or the first row of data items are used as column headings.

Comment: The problem is how to set the rowsource... See picture above

Answer (score 0):

I just create another list box and place it right above the primary listbox, make it flat etc. Then use the header row as the row source. That way any calculations made in the header row shows on the form as well.

Comment: This should have been a comment as it doesn't fully answer/explain the asked question. I suggest you to read Stackoverflow answering guidelines.